# How to get a specific character from within an Arraylist of strings?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm working on a multicast simulation using weighted graphs and I need to create a set with given vertex "tuples" in the arraylist. I have the following:

```
Set<Integer> vertex = new HashSet<Integer>(); // A set to hold the vertices

ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList( new  String[]
                                                         {"0 4","4 0","4 5","5 4",
                                                          "5 9","9 5","0 8","8 0",
    /* Arraylist of vertices above */                    "0 3","3 5","5 3","3 9",
                                                          "1 3","3 1"}));

vertex.add(values.get(0.charAt(0))); // <<<< How do I do this?
```

In my actual program I will obviously have a loop running through the array so I won't be referencing the values directly like such but here is an example: I need to add, (0,4) to the hashset but I don't know how to get 0 and 4 from the string value inside the arraylist. Any ideas? Should I be using a different data structure to store the vertices, maybe?

Comment: You need to first `get` a `String`, and only **then** can you use `charAt`. So, the question becomes, how do you get just one String from the list?

Comment: Oh, so store each individual value in a string then use charAt. Got it! Would you mind writing that as an answer so I can upvote it and mark this as answered? @cricket_007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a very trivial solution, so I won't just hand code, but you need a String variable that you can call the `charAt` method on.

You can either do that with literally a temporary variable, but you can also use method chaining like you tried, but you're just missing a bracket after the 0 in the `get`